# Consecutio temporum

Tags: tenses

In a sentence like scio quid dixeris, is it mandatory to use the subjunctive?

Is it a mistake if I use the indicative instead of subjunctive and say "scio quid dixisti" ?

Were all/most Latinophones following consecutio temporum rules?

Comment: I'm most familiar with consecutio temporum being a rule about the _tense_ of a subordinate verb, not its mood. But it sounds like you're asking about the mood instead, whether a verb should be indicative or subjunctive. Is that correct? (If so, I'm going to edit the title of the question to better reflect that.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is from Wheelock's book: "a primary tense of the indicative must be followed by a primary tense of the subjunctive, and an indicative historical tense must be followed by a historical subjunctive tense" - since in these books they are putting the emphasis on the moods, I think consecutio relates to both tense and mood, but I'm not sure about this. That is why I ask. You can edit the title, no problem with that.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is, the *consecutio temporum* doesn't apply to **all** subordinate clauses—only some specific types that take the subjunctive. You mention Wheelock's description in a comment:

> A primary tense of the indicative must be followed by a primary tense of the subjunctive, and an indicative historical tense must be followed by a historical subjunctive tense.

But this doesn't mean that indicative verbs always have to be followed by subjunctive verbs. Rather, it means that **when** an indicative verb is followed by a subjunctive verb, their tenses have to come from the same sequence. (And even this isn't as absolute a rule as Wheelock says—but that's a separate issue.)

In this particular construction, the *indirect question*, it's standard to have the subordinate verb be in the subjunctive. But there are equivalent constructions which use the indicative, like a relative clause: *sciō quod dixistī*. If a construction calls for the subjunctive, *then* the *consecutio temporum* comes into play—but it's an *effect* of using the subjunctive, not the cause of it. (The *cause* is that this is an indirect question construction, and indirect questions take the subjunctive.)

To answer your second question: yes, in general most Latin authors did follow the *consecutio temporum*. But, like most rules in linguistics, it wasn't absolute. There are also a number of exceptions written by native speakers, which grammarians have tried to explain away in various ways with varying degrees of success.